# Show coupon code in newsletter subscription success message

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, coupon, newsletter

I need to show dynamically generated coupon code into my newsletter subscription success message in frontend:

I installed an extension of popup newsletter subscription module in Magento version 1.9.1.0. It's working well and sending the dynamic coupon code in mail, but I need to show a dynamically generated coupon code in my newsletter subscription success message in frontend. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you share the code for other people can advice you?

Comment: can you explain which code you want to see is it controller page code or model page code?

Comment: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/activated-newsletter-coupon.html

Answer (score 0):

So after the some action the customer gets the email with the code.

I assume in the code it's a controller action.

What you need is to add a view for this action (block and template) and in the template show generated coupon code.  And the coupon generation function you already have in the module.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I could not do that process , can you please let me have code snippet of this functionality.I am using this   http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/newsletter-subscription-with-free-gift-coupon-popup.html