# How Add dynamic coupon code at Newsletter subscriptions

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, coupon

I need to add dynamic coupon code at the confirm newsletter mail to sent subs.

I look this post: [Show coupon code in newsletter subscription success message](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55643/show-coupon-code-in-newsletter-subscription-success-message), 
but don't help me.

I don't need a popup, but I need to use core newsletter subscription form

ps: I tryed this extension: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/activated-newsletter-coupon.html and when open backend configuration show me error 500.

Thanks